# How do I implement logging in an enum singleton?

Tags: java, logging, enums, singleton

I'm using an enum singleton, but implementing logging is troublesome. This:

```
public enum Foo {
  INSTANCE;

  private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName());

  ...
}
```

The logger is instantiated in the way that I would instantiate a logger for a normal Java class, but of course I get the following error:

```
Foo.java: illegal reference to static field from initializer
```

Is there an equivalent way to log in enum singletons?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In answer to your question, just make the logger static...

BTW, I think its standard practice to use a static logger even for object instances.  In other words, the logger is on the class; all objects use the static logger references.

See

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Most of the examples of using a logger in there have the logger as a static property...

Comment: +1 for static logger. SLF4J has an interesting discussion too: http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#declared_static

Answer (score 5):

Log dynamically:

```
Logger.getLogger(Foo.class.getName()).info("log info");
```

Comment: It's really not if you use an IDE. set yourself up a template. In Eclipse, I use "log" to expand into this template fro a quick debug log entry.

Comment: What is the advantage of that method?

Comment: Instances are IOC-friendly and can be used to define a different logging environment for each application in a server. Slightly slower, but there are certain advantages (and other disadvantages as well).

Answer (score 2):

A bit shorter: use a method: *logger().debug(...)*

```
private static Logger logger()
{
    if(logger == null)
    {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(AnEnum.class);
    }

    return logger;
}

/** Logger **/
private static Logger logger;
```